# Mapping Profile Attribute to a boolean Sales Cloud field not possible

Tags: marketing-cloud

I've been trying to map one of the Profile Attributes to a boolean field in Sales Cloud, but I'm getting the following message without any further explanation:

> "That mapping is not allowed"

The original field in Sales Cloud is a true/false field, and it's synchronizing to MC along other fields we are using into a synched DE. 
I also tried restricting the values for this field to true/false, but it didn't help.

Did anyone else stumble upon this error?

[image]

Comment: Are you able to map any Boolean field at all? I tried to map profile attribute to various Sales cloud boolean fields and received the mapping error in all cases.

Comment: I also checked out this page: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_si_map_attributes.htm&type=5 Not quite sure what do they mean by this: "Preference attributes require Boolean data types for the Lead or Contact field in Salesforce." under the Data Types heading. While mapping Profile attribute there is no option to select boolean data type. They have provided only 3 options: Text, Numeric and Date. So I am not sure if we need to raise a support ticket to get the boolean field enabled or not.

Comment: @KratiGarg you are right, I am unable to map any boolean fields - will create a support case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I heard back from support and was able to map my boolean field correctly:

> For field of boolean data type, you must map it in Preference
>   management. Preference Attributes can only be mapped to Checkbox
>   fields in Salesforce.
>
> Profile Attributes cannot be mapped to Lookup Relationships,
>   Checkboxes, or Picklists (Multi-Select).

Please find below document further information:
Best practices for mapping Salesforce fields to Marketing Cloud Attributes 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213311&type=1